# JAAS authentication not invoked on subsequent requests

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jaas

I am using a custom module to authenticate users of my SOAP interface using Jboss, based on JAAS. It is just a simple BASIC authentication, using username and password.

I am currently using SOAPUI to test the interface, and setting authorization credentials on the specific request. This is the problem:

1. Making a request with user1, all works as expected, getting authentizied.
2. Making a request with user2, all works as expected, getting authentizied.
3. Requests are no longer running through the JAAS authentication code, and subject not updated with roles etc.

So in short making subsequent requests with different users make no difference. BTW, I am using "Close connection after request" on SOAP UI as I thought this may be the source. But the problem continued.

What am I missing in the request cycle here, should the custom module not be run on every request?

Regards,
OM

Comment: It's a bit vague but since you're using JBoss, I assume you are performing the request from an EJB? If that is the case, a stateful or stateless one?

Comment: Possibly SOPAUI stores a cookie which survives the connection close. Have you tried a form-based authentication? Have you tried to logout explicitly? Is there an option to clear all cookies etc.?

Comment: @user1109519 , no I am making the requests from soapUI, an external client.

Comment: @Beryllium , that was my initial thought as well so chose the "Close connection after request" option. I do not see any other cookie option? Looking at the request being sent, it does not mention any cookie header being set either.

Comment: But the logout() function of the authentication module is never invoked either.

Comment: @OMA Ah ok, I thought you were mocking the webservice with SOAPui and using jboss as client :) The same question applies sort of though: what kind of webservice are you exposing in JBoss?

Comment: @user1109510 , it's a stateless session bean that is exposing the webservice ATStateless
ATSecurityDomain("domain")
ATWebContext(contextRoot = "/service", urlPattern = "/*", authMethod = "BASIC", transportGuarantee = "NONE", secureWSDLAccess = true)
ATWebService(endpointInterface = "com.remoteInterface", serviceName = "name")
ATSOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out in the end myself. There was no wrong settings etc on the client side. But when setting up the module in jboss's standalone.xml, the cache-type was set.

If cache-type is removed from the security-domain section, the module will be called on every request.

```
            <security-domain name="example" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.example.loginModule" flag="required"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: This was also particularly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280812/jaas-customloginmodule-not-called-for-second-location-a-user-logs-in

Comment: JBoss EAP 6 also caches the Principal in the HttpSession for quick retrieval - regardless of the presence of the Principal being stored in the JAAS cache (default implementation is Infinispan).