# JAAS CustomLoginModule not called for second location a user logs in

Tags: java, security, authentication, jboss, jaas

We implemented a `CustomLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule` for JAAS in JBoss EAP 6.2.

The login module contains functionality that needs to be handled every login and it appears that for some logins, the `CustomLoginModule` is not called.

We notice that when a user logs in at two separate locations, the second login never enters the `CustomLoginModule` methods: `initialize, login, logout, getRoleSets, getUsersPassword, createPasswordHash, validatePassword` .
It seems like the logged in user's password and roles are cached and reused.

If the second user logs in with a wrong password, the validatePassword method is called.

So my question is: how can I force every login to go through the `CustomLoginModule`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was confused by possible solutions implementing a custom JaasSecurityManagerService mbean, or at least define it's DefaultCacheTimeout: [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CachingLoginCredentials) and [link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/The_JBoss_Security_Extension_Architecture-The_JaasSecurityManagerService_MBean.html)

The answer proved much simpler, and I got it from [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/203527) (scroll to the answer by Darren Jones for Wildfly, complemented by Artur Mioduszewski for EAP6.1).

I use EAP 6.2, so used the following configuration in my standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.4">
    <cache-container name="security" default-cache="auth-cache">
        <local-cache name="auth-cache" batching="true">
            <expiration lifespan="*INSERT_CACHE_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
...
<security-domain name="myJaasDomain" cache-type="infinispan">
```

Setting the timeout to 0 shows undefined behaviour, so I used 1 ms.

Comment: another way to do it is to remove cache-type out of the security-domain entirely

Answer (score 4):

The key to answer this problem is the security-domain configuration. The `cache-type="infinispan"` (or `"default"` as main examples around the web) activates the use of `JBossCachedAuthenticationManager`. It stores the data of recent logins (with credentials) and compares input with cached entries. If a cached entry is found it validates if user/password is valid. If valid, it continues without executing the authenthicate method again.

If you remove the cache-type tag as @steven suggested, you remove the use of the cache when checking the credentials and then force the authentication mechanism again.

Messing with the configuration is not a good idea if your settings include more security-domains.